# Can't close fancybox after automatic open on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox-3

I have a problem with fancybox that opens automatically on page load. After I click the close button the fancybox opens again.

Could you help me out please?

```
<script>
 jQuery(function($){
  $(".popup-wrapper").fancybox({
  'padding': '0',
  'max-width': '50%',
  'max-height': '50%',
  'autoSize': false,
  'transitionIn': 'fade',
  'transitionOut': 'fade',
  });

 $(".popup-wrapper").trigger('click');
});
</script>
```

css:

```
.popup-wrapper {
 display: none;
 width: 50%;
 height: auto;
   img {
    width: 80%;
   height: auto;
 }
}
```

the php & html

```
<?php $args = array('post_type' => 'popup', 'showposts' => 5,); 
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args ); ?>
<?php while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();
$meta = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'popup_details', true ); ?>

<?php if (is_array($meta) && $meta['displayPopup'] === '1') { ?>
<div class="popup-wrapper col-12 col-xl-12">
    <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
</div><!-- .popup-wrapper -->
<?php }; 
endwhile;

wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

**UPDATE**
The problem appears only when I click on the close button. When I hit the ESC button or click on the black background then the box closes with no problem.

Comment: Could you post some html/css? Just a hunch but it sounds like the code is firing twice. Might be something to do with .trigger(). If you comment that line out does it work?

Comment: ok, I have updated my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by adding `preventDefault` to my code and now it works. Hope this help somebody in the future.

```
jQuery(function($){
 $(".popup-wrapper").fancybox({
  'padding': '0',
  'autoSize': true,
  'transitionIn': 'fade',
  'transitionOut': 'fade',
 });

 $(".popup-wrapper").trigger('click');

 $(document).find('.fancybox-close-small').on('click', function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
      self.close(e);
 });
});
```